# OSX Lion BootCamp: Win7 update breaks OSX, writes to OSX partition

Tags: windows-7, macos, windows-update, boot-camp

I've had this happen twice now: I boot to win7 in boot camp, and install the windows updates as indicated by windows. After rebooting , osx loads slowly at first, and disk util tells me there are errors on mac partion.
I rebooted to RestoreDisc where disc utility says it cannot fix errors and to format whole disk!
I booted into Windows again, and saw that there is a temp folder on the mac partition full of windows executables!
Now I have read that win7 updates will write to any adjacent partition, using it as a swap drive!

UPDATE:
I just decided to not continue punishing myself and got Parallels7. Apparently W!ndow$ uses the next partition as a swap drive regardless whether it has access or not. ugh.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this, but my understanding is that you can avoid this problem by dismounting the OS X volume before running Windows Update.  [This Mac OS X Hint](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20090828100459305) suggests using the `mountvol` command to mount & unmount the volume.  [This Apple KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3841) suggests temporarily disabling the AppleMNT.sys driver and rebooting.

Comment: Thanks, but I went with the VM solution. It just feels less painful.